# htaccess how differentiate between folder or url?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this problem, I'm using my url like this:

If somebody is coming to the website from a referral the have something like `https://myweb.site/UERHF723R` so my htaccess have this:

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?ref=$1 [L,QSA]`

but how I can send somebody to `https://myweb.site/foldername` without send them to index.php as a variable.

I think I can use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foldername
RewriteRule .* /foldername/index.php
```

But I don't want to to this for every new folder, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?ref=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In this way, you only rewrite urls that are not directories (-d) or files (-f)
The second line is therefore not mandatory in your case.